# How to Call Webmethods through android without using third party tool

Tags: android

I have Created *.net webservice method* `authenticateuser` and need to call it from an *Android* application. How can I do it without using a third party tool?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  Are you wanting to post data to your web service and read back a result?

Comment: you don't need any third party tool for this . Android has the SAX and DOM API which you can use for parsing.

Comment: do you want to call the methods by POST or GET Method??

Answer (score 1):

If you want to call the .net web service and using POST method then follow below:

```
 DefaultHttpClient  httpclient = getClient();

  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("complete address");

  List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(4);//number should be the amount of parameters 

   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param_name", "param_value"));
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param_name", "param_value"));

    try {
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity ht = response.getEntity();

        BasicResponseHandler myHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String endResult = "";

            endResult = myHandler.handleResponse(response); 

            System.out.println("endResuilt*** = "+endResult);

            dataStream = endResult;
        }catch(Exception e){
           //Catch the Exception
        }
```

Hope this helps!